# Using systemd to start vpnc results in 'unknown host'?

Tags: vpn, systemd

I'm trying to connect to vpnc using a systemd service file. The service file runs a script, myscript.sh, which, among other things, runs:

```
sudo vpnc myhost
```

Upon booting the device, the other commands are correctly executed, but the vpn is not connected, and gives me the error message:

```
vpnc: unknown host `myhost.com'
```

However, if I run the service file manually using

```
systemctl start myservice.service
```

then the vpn is successfully started.

My service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=VPN Start
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Environment=DISPLAY=:0.0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/myscript.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=pi
Group=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
systemctl status myservice.service
```

includes this message:

```
pi: TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/vpnc myhost
```

I have already done:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online
```

and that hasn't appeared to help.

Answer (score 1):

It might be to late, but maybe anyone else stumbles upon this.

I had the same issue although I configured the VPN through the GUI.

I found out eventually that my `/etc/resolv.conf` was a symlink to a configuration file some third party VPN software I sometimes use installed. Although the entries in that file looked fine it only worked, when I deleted the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink and created a new normal file.

TL;DR:

1. Backup `/etc/resolv.conf`
2. Remove symlink
3. Create new `/etc/resolv.conf` and populate it with your preferred configuration

After that my VPN worked like a charm.